# How to subclass the builtin function class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python you can add metadata to functions by way of attributes, as discussed in the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#types):

> Function objects also support getting and setting arbitrary attributes, which can be used, for example, to attach metadata to functions.

I have a function that takes another function as input, expecting it to have such a metadata attribute available. When using the type `Callable` to annotate this function, I cannot enforce this attribute being present. Hence, I want to rather make a subclass of the built in `function` class that ensures the presence of metadata, that I can use in type annotations.

There is only one small issue: I can't find references to this class except in runtime. For instance the `builtins` module does not have a function class as far as I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to subclass [the built-in function type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) in Python.

```
>>> class MyFunction(type(lambda: None)):
...     pass
...
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

Consider using a *callable class* instead: create a user-defined type which documents the expected metadata attribute(s) and defines a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.